# React-native Picker selected text issue

Tags: react-native

When i select a item in my Picker component, the value of state changes but the visual selected item not.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        localSelecionado: { value: null, index: 0 }
    };
}

<Picker
    style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}
    itemStyle={{ alignItems: 'center' }}
    selectedValue={this.state.localSelecionado}
    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ localSelecionado: { value: itemValue, index: itemIndex } })}>

    <Picker.Item key={null} label="Selecione..." value={0} />
    {this.props.lista.map((local) => {
        return (
            <Picker.Item key={local._id} label={local.nome} value={local._id} />
        )
    })}

</Picker>
<Label style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}>Index: {this.state.localSelecionado.index}</Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an object in `selectedValue`, you should change `selectedValue={this.state.localSelecionado}` to `selectedValue={this.state.localSelecionado.value}`.

Hope this will help!